# cannot generate and compile "lib" and "include"

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, codeblocks, mysql++

i want to generate the two files "inlclude" and "lib"
i used code::blocks in windows with MinGW, and i have already found words like "MYSQL_WIN_DIR" in "the file called "mysql++.bkl",and change it with the path of "Mysql Connector.c6.1" in my computer, after i use bakefile which is a tool to help compile  by input orders (such as "bakefile_gen -f mingw" and "mingw32-make -f Makefile.mingw" ,"install.hta"in cmd), i only get one file named"inlclude" ,i cann't find the file"lib",so the libmysqlpp.a and mysqlpp.dll don't exist!!!, where is the lib of mysql++?  what can i do? ,the informations in cmd as follow:

```
C:\1MyFiles\TEMP\mysql++-3.2.5>mingw32-make -f Makefile.mingw
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_beemutex.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_beemutex.o -MFmysqlpp_beemutex.o.d -MD -MP lib/beemutex.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_cmdline.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_cmdline.o -MFmysqlpp_cmdline.o.d -MD -MP lib/cmdline.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_connection.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_connection.o -MFmysqlpp_connection.o.d -MD -MP lib/connection.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_cpool.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_cpool.o -MFmysqlpp_cpool.o.d -MD -MP lib/cpool.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_datetime.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_datetime.o -MFmysqlpp_datetime.o.d -MD -MP lib/datetime.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_dbdriver.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_dbdriver.o -MFmysqlpp_dbdriver.o.d -MD -MP lib/dbdriver.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_field_names.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_field_names.o -MFmysqlpp_field_names.o.d -MD -MP lib/field_names.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_field_types.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_field_types.o -MFmysqlpp_field_types.o.d -MD -MP lib/field_types.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_manip.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_manip.o -MFmysqlpp_manip.o.d -MD -MP lib/manip.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_myset.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_myset.o -MFmysqlpp_myset.o.d -MD -MP lib/myset.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_mysql++.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_mysql++.o -MFmysqlpp_mysql++.o.d -MD -MP lib/mysql++.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_mystring.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_mystring.o -MFmysqlpp_mystring.o.d -MD -MP lib/mystring.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_null.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_null.o -MFmysqlpp_null.o.d -MD -MP lib/null.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_options.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_options.o -MFmysqlpp_options.o.d -MD -MP lib/options.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_qparms.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_qparms.o -MFmysqlpp_qparms.o.d -MD -MP lib/qparms.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_query.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_query.o -MFmysqlpp_query.o.d -MD -MP lib/query.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_result.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_result.o -MFmysqlpp_result.o.d -MD -MP lib/result.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_row.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_row.o -MFmysqlpp_row.o.d -MD -MP lib/row.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_scopedconnection.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_scopedconnection.o -MFmysqlpp_scopedconnection.o.d -MD -MP lib/scopedconnection.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_sql_buffer.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_sql_buffer.o -MFmysqlpp_sql_buffer.o.d -MD -MP lib/sql_buffer.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_sqlstream.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_sqlstream.o -MFmysqlpp_sqlstream.o.d -MD -MP lib/sqlstream.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_ssqls2.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_ssqls2.o -MFmysqlpp_ssqls2.o.d -MD -MP lib/ssqls2.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_stadapter.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_stadapter.o -MFmysqlpp_stadapter.o.d -MD -MP lib/stadapter.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_tcp_connection.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_tcp_connection.o -MFmysqlpp_tcp_connection.o.d -MD -MP lib/tcp_connection.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_transaction.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_transaction.o -MFmysqlpp_transaction.o.d -MD -MP lib/transaction.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_type_info.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_type_info.o -MFmysqlpp_type_info.o.d -MD -MP lib/type_info.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_uds_connection.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_uds_connection.o -MFmysqlpp_uds_connection.o.d -MD -MP lib/uds_connection.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_utility.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_utility.o -MFmysqlpp_utility.o.d -MD -MP lib/utility.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_vallist.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_vallist.o -MFmysqlpp_vallist.o.d -MD -MP lib/vallist.cpp
g++ -c -o mysqlpp_wnp_connection.o -g -O0 -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DMYSQLPP_NO_DLL -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include"   -MTmysqlpp_wnp_connection.o -MFmysqlpp_wnp_connection.o.d -MD -MP lib/wnp_connection.cpp
g++ -shared -fPIC -o mysqlpp.dll @mysqlpp.dll.rsp  -Wl,--out-implib=libmysqlpp.a -g -mthreads -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib"   -lwsock32 -lmysql
C:/1MyFiles/Mycpp/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib/libmysql.dll when searching for -lmysql
C:/1MyFiles/Mycpp/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib/libmysql.dll when searching for -lmysql
C:/1MyFiles/Mycpp/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmysql
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile.mingw:363: mysqlpp.dll] Error 1
```

Comment: Is there a file `libmysql.a` or  `libmysql.dll.a` in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib` or anywhere else where the linker can find it (e.g. via environment path `LIBRARY_PATH`)?

Comment: Thank you for your attention,the MySQL C client has 32-bit libraries , i didn't realize that my systerm environment value sets 64-bit compile as default ,so when i use bakefile(tools for helping compile by using 32bit compile) ,it generate some configuration files which invoke systerm-environment-default-value-compile behind the scenes but i don't know. In summary ,the real problem is that i use cross-compile in the same code simultaneously, and that 's the reason.